# Could not find cordova integration in the default project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

following the [official getting started tutorial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/running) I get the following error when I try to deploy the application in my phone using this command: `ionic serve --devapp` (it works on browser):

```
[ERROR] Could not find cordova integration in the default project.
```

I get this error both on Windows and MacOS.
I'm using **Node 6.4.1** and **Ionic CLI 4.10.3**

Does the official tutorial missing something?

Comment: Add `"cordova": {}` in `"integrations"` of `ionic.config.json`

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I had the same issue. In fact, with the default project, you have to copy the cordova assets to prepare the native build for mobile. 
You can find more info here : [Ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-prepare)

Try this :

```
ionic cordova prepare
```

And then go again with :

```
ionic serve --devapp
```

Comment: While this might solve the OPs issue, it would be appreciated if you elaborated *how* and *why* it does.

Comment: Perfectly worked here in Ubuntu 16 today May 17 of 2019. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is 100% correct .

But the reason why this occurred for me was that somehow the default was capacitor and not cordova.

so first i ran

```
ionic integrations disable capacitor
```

then ran

```
ionic cordova prepare
```

which solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is 100% correct follow this step :

```
1. ionic start --type=angular

2. ionic integrations disable capacitor

    2.1 delete - node , platform 
    
3. ng add @ionic/cordova-builders

4. ionic cordova build android
```